# Best Java EE server for ColdFusion

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, coldfusion

What is the best Java EE server to deploy coldfusion 9 on? I know there is Tomcat but i'm sure there are others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ColdFusion support matrix](http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/pdfs/cf9_support_matrix_4_ue.pdf) lists a limited number of Java EE servers that they support:

- WebLogic Server 9.2, 10.3
- WebSphere Application Server ND 6.1, ND 7
- JRun Updater 7
- JBoss 4.2, 5.01

Your choice from this list is going to be dictated by commercial realities, not technical ones - WebLogic and Websphere are the leading servers, but commercial (and expensive); JBoss is free (although you can pay for a support contract); JRun is just rubbish, and I suspect only supported because if I remember correctly, JRun and ColdFusion used to be the same platform.

Having said all that, CF may run just fine on any other appserver, but that would be unsupported.

Comment: ColdFusion and JRun were indeed both products from Allaire. Actually, I had almost forgotten its existence. According to wikipedia, *Adobe announced in August 2007 to discontinue new feature development for JRun. The ColdFusion team will continue to make changes to its underlying Java engine as they require.* (source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macromedia_JRun).

Comment: "JRun is just rubbish" - Why? We have several production servers on JRun, without a problem so far. What's better with the others?

Comment: OK, maybe that was a bit harsh, but JRun is a dead duck. The only reason to use it is if you've already invested in it.

Comment: Well, it comes free with the CF standalone installation. Anyway - would there be a compelling reason to switch?

Comment: JRun has no future development planned, but it works just fine as an app server supporting CF.

Comment: I see that Adobe only lists paid for application servers (or their own Jrun). Does anyone have experience running Coldfusion on Glassfish or Tomcat?

Comment: @nedlud: JBoss isn't paid for (unless you really want to)

Answer (score 1):

You need to answer two or three questions to decide:

- Do you know enough about it to not
  want to just use JRun?
- Which Java EE servers do you know well
  enough to support (or know the best)?
- Which of those are on the supported
  servers list?

Answer (score 0):

If you can deploy Cold Fusion on any Java EE app server, there are lots to choose from:

1. WebLogic
2. JBOSS
3. Glassfish
4. Jetty
5. WebSphere

Pick the one that fits your budget.

I've listed these in my order of preference.  I think WebLogic is still the best Java EE app server out there.  Let's hope Oracle doesn't kill it.

Comment: I totally agree with your sentence about WebLogic and Oracle. Regarding the list, and the order, have a look at http://agoncal.wordpress.com/2009/12/12/o-application-servers-where-art-thou/, you'll see why I start to not like JBoss as much as before (but still more than WebSphere).

Comment: Pascal, that's a terrific link.  I recently found my way to the links you post in your profile and was glad that I did.  Your posts are terrific, so it's no surprise that other material you have on the web is equally good.  I'll be coming back for more.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad you find it interesting. And thanks a lot for the compliments.

Answer (score 0):

I built a ColdFusion 6.1 application for a national 401k provider deployed on JBoss and it worked very well. Actually, I was able to run CF 6 on a 64-bit JVM because I was no longer hindered by JRun.